# Design Question - Stock and OnSale Table

Tags: database-design, ms-access

**Background :**

I'm designing a solution for a repair toy association.
Since they have office - I'll use Access.

**Plot :**

[image: Database Overview]
Stock will store items - 
I choose this primary key (Item_Id,Record_date) because I had to able :

- Ex : Item1 entered by User_X multiple times at different dates.
- Items will be stored in stock **THEN** will be put online via Ebay
  (Ebay API isn't on question - they don't want full automatisation)

  ```
  Stock(Id_item, Record_date, Record_user_id)
  OnSale(Id_item, Record_date, Record_user_id, OnSale_date,....)
  ```

**Questions :**

- Can't decide if I am allowed to merge Stock & OnSale Table & use Price column as a test to differenciate them ? Or should they be separated ?
- Is that correct to have 2 1-to-many relationship linked to one table (User - Stock & User1 - Stock)

If I am completly wrong, I'm really open to any suggestions that could improve my knowledge.

Edit : [image: DB updated]

Thank for the comment. My first version of the db using SoldOut & Remove Table as "Log table". I will make the changes about separating Stock & OnSale Items.
Correct me if i'm wrong :

1. Item is entered in stock
2. Item moves to OnSale Table when someone write the full spec.
3. Item moves to SoldOut when it has been sold.

Best regards, Falt

Comment: I'd have Stock and Sale as separate tables. But (Item_Id, Record_Date) as a PK won't prevent the same item being entered on different dates, just on the same date. The flow is 1) you receive item. 2) you put it into the stock table. 3) You sell it - item moves to the Sold table. You appear to be over complicating what is (or should be) simple. What's wrong with Item_Id as the PK? I don't fully understand the difference between the User and the User_1 table - care to expand? Why not just have 1 table User?

Comment: @Vérace I wanted to write able instead of prevent.Ex : User_x enter Item1 multiples times but yeah Item_Id solves that. About user_1 it's just Access that doesn't want to 1 to many relationship from 1 table to another one multiples times. There is 2 step in the association : 1 people will enter item in the stock . Later, another guy (maybe the same maybe not) will pick 1 item and put in on sale and write the description, weight, dimensions of the repaired toy. That's why i wanted to track both.

Comment: @Vérace Made the changes suggested. It seems really better.